# How to use SSL over multiple domains in AWS using ELB (Single Machine)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, amazon-elb, opencart2.3

We're currently using Opencart - 2.3.x to serve multiple domains under one AWS Instance with ELB.

We've set HTTPS for one domain but for other domains we're not able to do the same as we cannot make duplicate listeners.

Has anyone faced a similar issue in the past.

Answer (score 0):

There are four common alternatives:

- create one ELB for each certificate and associate the instance with all of the ELBs, or
- obtain a single certificate for all the domains using Amazon Certificate Manager and associate it with the ELB, or
- use the one certificate on the ELB and attach each of the other certificates to its own CloudFront distribution, pointing to the ELB and whitelisting the Host header for forwarding to the origin, or
- use a Classic ELB in TCP (not HTTP) mode with SSL disabled; configure SSL on the instance, and install the certificates there, and not the ELB.

Comment: I am new to this, would it be possible for you to share any document / reference where this can be further reviewed.. I like the first and the last point that you mentioned!